# Modular store in Vuex with Vue JS is not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vuex-modules

I am developing a web application using Vue + Vuex. I am new to Vue. What I am doing now is I am trying to integrate Vuex into my Vue application. But when I use the modularised Vuex, it is not working.

This is my store file called PersonalInfoFormStore.js

```
export default {
    namespaced : true,
    state : {
        name : 'this is my name'
    }
}
```

Then in the app.js, I set up the Vuex store like this

```
import Vuex from 'vuex';

import PersonalInfoFormStore from './PersonalInfoFormStore';

//other packages


Vue.component("application-form", require('./components/PersonalInfoForm.vue'));

Vue.use(Vuex);

const store = new Vuex.Store({
    modules : {
        PersonalInfoFormStore
    }
});

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    //other bit of code
    store: store
});
```

Then in the PersonalInfoForm.vue, I tried to access the state value like this.

```
mounted() {

        alert(this.$store.PersonalInfoFormStore.state.name)
        //alert(this.$store.getters.count)
    }
```

Then in the console, I got this error

```
app.js:664 [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined"

found in
```

How can I fix it? If I do not use the modularised store and put all in a single store, everything is working fine. But I want the modularised store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
alert(this.$store.PersonalInfoFormStore.state.name)
```

into

```
alert(this.$store.state.PersonalInfoFormStore.name)
```

Comment: I still have another issue. I cannot call the mutator though. like this.$store.PersonalInfForm.commit("setName", name)

Comment: try `this.$store.commit('PersonalInfoFormStore/setName', name)`

Comment: @WaiYanHein Sorry was making lunch, did the solution of the comment above this work?

Comment: Thanks. I removed the namespaced: true. It works. But ur one is proper solution. Cheers mate.

Answer (score 2):

I think it should be `this.$store.state.PersonalInfoFormStore.name` instead